# Cannot add record on the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have this form that adds record when i click on the save customer it 
will be added on the database and display the add record on the gridview.
 
The gridview is connected on the database. (there's no 
problem with the gridview.)

Here is my problem.. 
i can't add records on the database once I click on the button.
I think the problem is in the code behind.

can anyone help me what's wrong with my code?

Default.aspx

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--Needed for JavaScript IntelliSense in VS2010--%>
            <%--For VS2008 replace RadScriptManager with ScriptManager--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Put your JavaScript code here.
    </script>

    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <div>
        <div id="padding-left">
        <br />
            <div id="border">
                <div style="float: none; height: 30px; padding-bottom: 3px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Customer ID:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtCustomerID" runat="server" Enabled="false" />                    
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">First Name:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Middle Name:</div>                    
                    <div style="float: none;">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtMiddleName" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Last Name:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Address:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">    
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Contact Number:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtContactNumber" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Birthday:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">    
                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpBirthday" runat="server" />  
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Age:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">    
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>        

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">Gender:</div>
                    <div style="float: none;">    
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtGender" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                <div class="padLabel">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="InfoMessage" />
                </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: none; height: 30px;">
                    <div class="padLabel" style="float: none;">
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSaveCustomer" runat="server" Text="Add Customer" OnClick="btnSaveCustomer_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="padding-innerleft">
            <br />
            <div align ="right">
            <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnLogut" Text="Logout" OnClick="btnLogut_Click" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                GridLines="None">
                <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
                </HeaderContextMenu>
                <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>
                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CustomerID" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter CustomerID column"
                            HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" UniqueName="CustomerID">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FirstName" FilterControlAltText="Filter FirstName column"
                            HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" UniqueName="FirstName">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MiddleName" FilterControlAltText="Filter MiddleName column"
                            HeaderText="MiddleName" SortExpression="MiddleName" UniqueName="MiddleName">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LastName" FilterControlAltText="Filter LastName column"
                            HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" UniqueName="LastName">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Address" FilterControlAltText="Filter Address column"
                            HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" UniqueName="Address">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Birthday" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter Birthday column"
                            HeaderText="Birthday" SortExpression="Birthday" UniqueName="Birthday">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Age" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter Age column"
                            HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" UniqueName="Age">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Gender" FilterControlAltText="Filter Gender column"
                            HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" UniqueName="Gender">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactNumber" FilterControlAltText="Filter ContactNumber column"
                            HeaderText="ContactNumber" SortExpression="ContactNumber" UniqueName="ContactNumber">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditFormSettings>
                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                        </EditColumn>
                    </EditFormSettings>
                </MasterTableView>
                <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
                </FilterMenu>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [Address], [Birthday], [Age], [Gender], [ContactNumber] FROM [v.NewCustomer]">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

code behind

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);

    protected void btnSaveCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into v.NewCustomer(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, Birthday, Age, Gender, ContactNumber) values (@FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @Address, @Birthday, @Age, @Gender, @ContactNumber)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", dpBirthday.SelectedDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContactNumber.Text);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("NewCustomer", conn);
        //com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        //SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName.Text);
        //SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        //SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
        //SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@Birthday", dpBirthday.SelectedDate);
        //SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@Age", txtAge.Text);
        //SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("@Gender", txtGender.Text);
        //SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("@ContactNumber", txtContactNumber.Text);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p1);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p2);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p3);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p4);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p5);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p6);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p7);
        //com.Parameters.Add(p8);
        //conn.Open();
        //com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: Why create all these parameters instead of using `AddWithValue`? Why open the connection twice? Why don't you dispose `conn`? Is there any exception? What is the exception text? Why do you clear the parameters?

Comment: What happens when you try to add records? Does it throw an exception? Does the code just do nothing? Do only some of the records get added?

Comment: should i remove the try loop?

Comment: can you also provide the stored procedure for inserting records in DB? it should be "NewCustomer" SP.

Comment: i create the stored procedure on sql server

Comment: There us far *too much* code here. Isolate the problem to what is *actually wrong* and only post the *relevant parts* along with any *error indicator(s)*.

Comment: i just can't add it to the database. I really don't know what the problem here. can you please help me??? thanks

Comment: Run SQL Server Profiler. It will show you if the command to execute the sproc was successful.

Comment: The error could be in the stored procedure, as others have alluded to.  Does the stored procedure work as expected?  Does the account that is calling the procedure have permission to execute it?  We really need more information to go on to know if the error is in the database or in the code behind, or something else entirely.

Comment: I've already fix the problem. now my problem is i can't refresh the page after i add record.

Comment: @user1647667 what is going on with the page refresh?

Comment: once i add a new record, the gridview must refresh.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the `RadGrid` and see the newly added row, use `Rebind()` :

```
RadGrid1.Rebind();
```